# Is this the correct way to use Google Tag Manager for Gatsby

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-tag-manager, gatsby

I originally just added the Gatsby google tag manager plugin and added the GTM-XXXX to my config. But my SEO guy said he wants this code in the body of

```html
<!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->

<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXX"

height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>

<!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
```

So I copied the default html.js into src like this: `$ cp .cache/default-html.js src/html.js` and then made placed this jsx inside html.js

```js
        <body {...this.props.bodyAttributes}>
          {this.props.preBodyComponents}
          <div
            key={`body`}
            id="___gatsby"
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.props.body }}
          />
          {/* Google Tag Manager (noscript) */}

          <noscript>
            <iframe
              src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXX"
              height="0"
              width="0"
              style={{ display: 'none', visibility: 'hidden' }}
            />
          </noscript>

          {/* End Google Tag Manager (noscript) */}
          {this.props.postBodyComponents}
        </body>
```

Was my SEO guy correct in telling me to do this? Why did the Google Tag Gatsby Plugin not work just by itself?

Answer (score 1):

This is the noscript tag, which is only displayed for people who do not run Javascript. Since Gatsby is a Javascript framework people without Javascript will not see your website, so my educated guess is that the developers of that plugin did not deem it necessary to include the noscript tag (also the only tags/events that work in GTM without Javascript are custom image tags on pageload, so there is usually not much point in having them).

I do not see what this has to do with SEO. I do not think you need this.